# How to repeat a loop without using any bool?

Tags: c++

How to repeat switch statement using cin and without using of any bool and loop statements if it is possible. I need a very simple solution for this. I can do it on complex ways but I believe that it can be achieved in a very simple way if I am not wrong.

**Code:**

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    void addition();
    void multiplication();
    void quite();
    
    int main()
    {
       cout << "Press A to add" << '\n';
       cout << "Press M to Multiply" << '\n';
       cout << "Press Q to Quite" << '\n';
       cout << "Your choice: ";
       char choice;
       cin >> choice;
       switch (choice)
          {
             case 'A': case 'a':
                addition();
                break;
             case 'M': case 'm':
                multiplication();
                break;
             case 'Q': case 'q':
                quite();
                return 0;
          }
    }
    void addition()
    {
       double v1, v2;
       cout << "Enter first number: "; cin >> v1;
       cout << "Enter second number: "; cin >> v2;
       cout << "\n";
       cout << " Addition of values = " << (v1 + v2) << '\n';
    }
    void multiplication()
    {
       double v1, v2;
       cout << "Enter first number: "; cin >> v1;
       cout << "Enter second number: "; cin >> v2;
       cout << "\n";
       cout << " Multiplication of values = " << (v1 * v2) << '\n';
    }
    void quite()
    {
       return;
    }
```

Comment: why do you want it without loop ? If you want to repeat something then a loop *is* the simple solution. Not using a loop requires something more complex.

Comment: How can I call the main(); ?

Comment: There is always `goto`, if you really feel like, however this seems like a solution in search of a problem. What is the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one about not using a loop, but the problem to which the solution you believe involves not using a loop. Perhaps try to ask about the real problem? Or, is this just some question from some useless online C++ quiz site that nobody cares about?

Comment: @IndianaJones Just do `for(;;) { ... }`

Comment: when beginners say "I don't want xy, I want something simple" then often this is only because they are afraid to learn something new. On the long run learning how to use xy would be the right way and most of the time not using xy will lead to difficult and complex solutions. Do you have any reason not to use loops?

Comment: Are you allowed to include all the code in a `while(true) { ... }` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 It is allowed.

Comment: @Саша no it is not! I believe you can call `main` in C, but C++ is not C

Comment: @Саша Calling `main()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes my little 6 years old kid don't like loops and he want something without loop to repeat his code.

Comment: your kid seems to know about functions already, so put it in a function and then call the function several times

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes I hope he will accept it as he already knows functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural way to repeat code *is* a loop. If for some reason you do not want to use a loop you can put the code you want to repeat inside a function:

```
void foo() {
   // code goes here
}
```

and then call that function as often as you like:

```
foo();
foo();
foo();
```

However, its not simple to decide at runtime how often the function is called (without a loop or additional more complex measures).

*PS* there was some confusion about calling `main`, so just to get this straight: You are not allowed to call [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function). As far as I know it is allowed in C and this is one striking difference between C and C++.

Comment: Yes great Idea and solution

Answer (score 2):

In a small program like this, the forward declarations seem unneeded; just define the functions `addition()` and `multiplication()` before `main()`. Also I'm assuming `quite()` was intended to say `quit()` as in, quit the application. Returning from a void will never do this. `void quite() { return; }` literally does nothing at all.

I think this is what you are trying to do?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void addition()
{
   double v1, v2;
   cout << "Enter first number: "; cin >> v1;
   cout << "Enter second number: "; cin >> v2;
   cout << "Addition of values: ";
   cout << (v1 + v2);
   cout << endl;
}

void multiplication()
{
   double v1, v2;
   cout << "Enter first number: "; cin >> v1;
   cout << "Enter second number: "; cin >> v2;
   cout << "Multiplication of values: ";
   cout << (v1 * v2);
   cout << endl;
}

void selection_menu()
{
    cout << "Press A to Add" << endl;
    cout << "Press M to Multiply" << endl;
    cout << "Press Q to Quit" << endl;
    cout << "Your choice: ";
    char choice;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 'A': case 'a':
           addition();
           break;
        case 'M': case 'm':
           multiplication();
           break; 
        case 'Q': case 'q':
           return; // return to main(). Done using selection_menu().
    }
    selection_menu(); // start selection_menu() over again.
}

int main()
{
    selection_menu();
}
```